# NullPointerException getArguments() But have data

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I don't understands why nullpointer. I using Log check have data

Pls give me solution !

My code here

I pass data from ViewPagerActivity to PlayRadio

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main_activity);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args = intent.getExtras();
        Fragment playRadio = new PlayBlog();
        playRadio.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.pager, playRadio);
        transaction.commit();
        setUpView();
    }
```

In PlayRadio i get Value

```
public class PlayBlog extends Fragment {
    Context mContext;
    String Desciption;

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        PlayBlog playBlog = new PlayBlog();
        return playBlog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playradio_layout, container,
                false);
        mContext = container.getContext();
        final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                R.anim.rotate);
        ImageView splash = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.base);
        TextView tvDesciption = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_Marquee);
        Bundle args = this.getArguments();
        Desciption = args.getString(Constant.STRING_KEY);
        Log.i("", Constant.TAG + "PlayBlog " + Desciption);
        tvDesciption.setText(Desciption);
        splash.startAnimation(anim);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**`Error at line : Desciption = args.getString(Constant.STRING_KEY);`**

Error in logcat

```
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.tadev.blogradio.main.PlayBlog.onCreateView(PlayBlog.java:37)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-06 07:41:49.362: E/AndroidRuntime(2534):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**But when i check Desciption Logcat give have data. I don't understand it :(**

```
02-06 07:41:49.354: I/(2534): abc PlayBlog Blog Radio - Khi trưởng thành, bạn hay mang trong mình cảm giác lưng chừng cô đơn. Vì, không hẳn là không có người để quan tâm, chăm sóc, nhưng tại một thời điểm nào đó, một phút giây nào đó, bạn vẫn cảm thấy mình chông chênh và lạc lõng giữa chốn đông người...
```

Update Code

**class NewRadioFragment**

```
btnShowMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (item.getLink_play() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, item.getLink_play(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,
                            ViewPagerActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(Constant.STRING_KEY, Desciption);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I pass data from NewRadioFragment to ViewPagerActivity ( Bunble ) and send PlayRadio continue

Comment: Definitely args(bundle) is null because args(bundle) you are sending was empty(null)

Comment: Not null. I show logcat it have data

Comment: you call it wrong. you get it by calling `Bundle args = intent.getExtras();`

Comment: I change to Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args = intent.getExtras();
But don't work

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget `putString` to your `args`

```
args.putString(Constant.STRING_KEY,"testing");
playRadio.setArguments(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the First Point the line

```
Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
// Here args is null at the first run
```

**args** gives you null because there is no data in the intent. While if you need to send some data. create a intent or bundle then put your data

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(Constant.STRING_KEY,"testing");
playRadio.setArguments(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in receiving data in Fragment class.

Use the code:

```
String description = getArguments().getString(YOUR_KEY); // Simply use getArguments istead of this.getArguments()
```

It'll work.

Comment: Do u receiving a value of description in fragment?

Comment: "this" merely refers to the current instance - so in this case this.getArguments() and getArguments() are identical.